# ASP Net Не хочет сериализовывать ответ по Get-запросу

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, сериализация

Есть в Model класс Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

Есть контекст

```
class KorusContext : DbContext
{
    public KorusContext() : base("KorusConnection")
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Контроллер (например, Get-часть)

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    private KorusContext db = new KorusContext();

    [Route("getlist")]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees.ToList();
    }
```

После ввода /getlist выводится следующее:[image: System.InvalidOperationException]

Что касаемо сериализации, никаких трюков с этим я еще не вытворял. Предполагалось, что он просто должен выводить ответ в xml

Comment: В текст вопроса стоит добавить пример входной xml.

Comment: Добавьте метки: EF 6 или EF Core, ASP.NET или ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте смапить объекты из бд в DTO и их возвращать, не надо напрямую возвращать Entity.

Comment: В принципе, это как раз таки ответ. Только нужно объяснение: почему и зачем так делать. И желательна ссылка на документацию.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor это и ответ и совет. Ответ, потому что возврат простого DTO не будет содержать лишних зависимостей, которые невозможно десериализовать. А совет, потому что это хорошая практика для передачи данных между слоями приложения.

Comment: ладно ;)..........

Answer (score 0):

В MVC возвращаемый тип всегда ActionResult, если вам нужно вернуть именно страницу.

```
[Route("getlist")]
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
{
   return View(db.Employees.ToList());
}
```

А уже в представлении в `model` указываете следующее

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
```

Comment: Проект не предусматривает MVC-шаблон, view-часть буду делать отдельно. Впрочем, я нашел "заглушку", и ответ появляется.
В конструкторе контекста:
            base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Насколько опасно применять такой способ?

Comment: @ОлегСахаров не стоит проблемы Presentation слоя решать изменением логики работы с данными в бд, используйте DTO.